# Output flles keep getting ovewritten in Java

Tags: java, file, text, io, append

I've tried using BufferWriter format as well as FileWriter and PrintWriter each with a boolean true statement but they both behave the same as if I simply used a simple new File. Each time I get to the end of my program run, I call the function that writes the saved data to be appended. What ends up happening is that it overwrites the last saved data. I also have other code blocks that handle that text file as well and reformating them did nothing either.

```
//saves user information to "Users.txt" which will be called in the finally block after choice switch
public void writeUsers()
{
    try{

        File userFile = new File("Users.txt");
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(userFile);
        for(User i: userList) {    
        output.append("Name:");    
        output.println(i.getrealName());
        output.append("UID:");
        output.println(i.getidName());
        output.append("Password:");
        output.println(i.getpassword());
        output.println(" ");
        }
        output.close();
        System.out.print("Information has been saved to Users.txt\n");


    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnf) {
        System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: File Users.txt does not exist " + fnf);
    }
    catch(IOException eyeoh) {
        System.err.println("IOException: Error writing to Users.txt " + eyeoh);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The constructor `PrintWriter(File)` truncates the output file by default. The fact that `PrintWriter`'s method `append()` is called doesn't mean that it changes the mode of the file being opened. The behavior for  `append` is [described](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) as:

> An invocation of this method of the form out.append(csq) behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation

```
 out.write(csq.toString())
```

Here, you could use the constructor for `PrintWriter` that takes a `FileOutputStream` for appending

```
PrintWriter output = 
   new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(userFile, true /* append = true */));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the `PrintWriter` in append mode. Otherwise, when it first opens the file, it will clear it out. You can open it in append mode using:

```
new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(userFile,true)) // the `true` argument opens it in append mode
```

Answer (score 1):

PrintWriter by defualt truncates all existing data. To append you could, as other answers suggest, add a "true" argument to the constructor, which denotes "append = true,"

However, this is done more elegantly using java.nio.file.[Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) along with java.nio.file.[StandardOpenOption](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html), in which you can specify `StandardOpenOption.APPEND` as opposed to `StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING`
You can also specify things such as `StandardOpenOption.CREATE` which creates the file if it does not exist.

Additionally, remember to either place your `output.close()` statement in a `finally` block, or use try-with-resources. Otherwise if the flow of the program is interrupted (i.e. an Exception is thrown), `output` would remain unclosed. I personally use try-with-resources as it is less of a hassle: just declare all your resources, and they are closed automatically for you, whether or not the flow of the program is disrupted.

Also, as a general tip, print or pass the actual `Exception` object in your `catch` block, as opposed to just a "custom string" so as to not lose the original content of the `Exception` thrown. You can then concatenated that with whatever string you also want to print.

```
try(BufferedWriter bufWriter =
        Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("Users.txt"),
            Charset.forName("UTF8"),
            StandardOpenOption.WRITE, 
            StandardOpenOption.APPEND, //Makes this BufferedWriter append to the file, not truncate
            StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(bufWriter, true);)
{ 

    output.println("Text to be appended.");

}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.err.println(e + "Custom string");
}catch(IOException e){
    System.err.println(e + "Something eyeoh occurred...");
}
```

This uses a try-with-resources statement to declare and create a `BufferedWriter` using `java.nio.file.Files`, which accepts `StandardOpenOption` parameters, and an auto-flushing `PrintWriter` (denoted by "true" in the constructor) from the resultant `BufferedWriter`. `PrintWriter`'s `println()` method, can then be called to write to the file.

The `StandardOpenOption` parameters used in this code: opens the file for writing, only appends to the file, and creates the file if it does not exist.

`Paths.get("path here")` can be replaced with `new File("path here").toPath()`, if you are working exclusively with `File` objects (i.e. if you are using `JFileChooser.getSelectedFile()`)
And `Charset.forName("charset name")` can be modified to accommodate the desired `Charset`.